# Why "no http resource was found that matches the request URI"?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Hello guys i tried to make an api with ssms and visual studio. I saw a tutorial and although i made the steps exactly right, it returned me "no http resource was found that matches the request URI":

I have code in my controller like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using EmployeeDataAccess;

namespace EmployeeService1.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<Signage> Get()
        {
            using (Raw_DataEntities entities = new Raw_DataEntities())
            {
                return entities.Signages.ToList();
            }
        }

        public Signage Get(int fid)
        {
            using (Raw_DataEntities entities = new Raw_DataEntities())
            {
                return entities.Signages.FirstOrDefault(e => e.FID == fid);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace EmployeeService2
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

what am I doing so wrong? when i tried routing in a specified localhost it returns me this:

System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=No connection string named 'Raw_DataEntities' could be found in the application config file.
  Source=
  StackTrace:

Comment: You need to set a connection string in your web.config file, like the error says

Comment: @matt_lethargic web.config file connectionstring is not created...that's the mistake I think... so, do you have any idea what should i do? :/

Comment: Solved! :) Thank you

Comment: Do you want to update your question with how you solved it so that other people can learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You web.config is missing the connection string named 'Raw_DataEntities', add this pointing to your database and it should work.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Raw_DataEntities" connectionString="<your connection string" />
</connectionStrings>
```